# Display a video using opencv on swing

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I was trying to process a video using java opencv library and display the result on Swing GUI. I created a thread for the processing of each frame (video reading, filtering, canny and contour etc.) and update the result on Swing calling 'SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait':

```
VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture();
vc.open(...);
while(...){
vc.read(img);
// image processing on img;
// processed 'BufferedImage' image was saved in 'imgToPublish.img'
try{
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
            long t1 = Core.getTickCount();
            //displayWindow is a JLabel
            displayWindow.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgToPublish.img));
            displayWindow.revalidate();
            displayWindow.repaint();
            pack();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }catch (Exception exc){
                System.out.println(exc);
            }
            frameCount++;
            System.out.format("No %d display time %.2f on EDT %n",frameCount, ((double)(Core.getTickCount() - t1))/((double)tickCountFrequency)*1000.0);
        }
    });
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The speed is surprisingly fast, it only takes about 2ms for the display, which does not make sense, because the monitor cannot response that fast. What am I missing here? I want to wait til the processed image was actually displayed on the Swing UI.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using two threads for this?
If so you need them to synchronize their operations. Otherwise the display thread may display a partially completed image.
Having done the same thing, I think it's wiser to let the capture thread display the image whenever it's done processing it.
Forcing the threads to wait for each other essentially cancels the multi threading benefits (and causes a lot of headache).

Comment: Yes, I add a thread for image processing. So far, I haven't seen any incomplete images. I think for java swing, I have to use at lease two threads to display the image, because it's only thread safe on EDT for any UI related operations.